# Iterating through function names

Tags: vbscript

I have all the function names placed in an Excel sheet. I am connecting to this Excel sheet using an ADO connection in VBScript. Now I want to call each function I fetch from Excel.

I am using the below code, but it is giving me error. Can anyone tell me how to iterate and call different functions using a loop?

```
myXlsFile = "D:\func.xlsx"

Set objExcel = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

objExcel.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & myXlsFile & _
  ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;"

qry = "Select * from [Sheet1$]"
Set dbconnect = objExcel.Execute(qry)

While dbconnect.Eof <> True
  func_name = dbconnect.fields("func")
  "Call " & func_name & "()"
  dbconnect.MoveNext
Wend

Function sum()
  a = 10
  b = 10
  c = a+b
  MsgBox c
End Function

Function multiply()
  a = 10
  b = 10
  c = a*b
  MsgBox c
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, what you're trying to do here is a ***terrible*** approach at meta-programming. ***NEVER*** do something like this in production code!

With that said, VBScript won't interpret bare strings in your code. The line

```
"Call " & func_name & "()"
```

will simply raise an *Expected End of Statement* error. You need to [`Eval`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z5x4094%28v=vs.84%29), [`Execute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03t418d2%28v=vs.84%29), or [`ExecuteGlobal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/342311f1%28v=vs.84%29) such expressions.

```
Eval GetRef(func_name)

Execute func_name

ExecuteGlobal func_name
```

Comment: Thanka for the advice I used GetRef approach.